# Best Text Editor for NLP

Tags: nlp, text-editor

I have been working on NLP and using notepad++ for handling text files. It's good and some cases but problem is cant workout much with large scale files with lot of texts. VIM is not supporting UTF-8. Which one is the best text file handling editor with unicode support?

Answer (score 6):

vim supports utf-8 -

:set enc=utf-8

Answer (score 3):

Emacs, obviously.

Comment: Emacs is great, but I don't know if it's the first thing that comes to mind when talking about seamless processing of unicode files.

Comment: +1, upvoted because even though you're wrong, you tried your best.

Answer (score 2):

Vi, more obviously.

Comment: Upvoted, as you think along the same lines as I do.  Along the same lines, but wrongly :-)

Answer (score 2):

The [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) editor has support for UTF-8 and Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

I am happy with Sublime Text 2. Crossplatform (Win, Linux, Mac), performs well with regular expressions find&replace, lightweight but rich on plugins. You should give it a try ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Vim is, I guess, the best editor and offers following advantages:

- supports utf-8. If it isn't, add `set enc=utf-8` to your .vimrc file to make it support utf-8 permanently. For supporting utf-8 in only the current session, do `:set enc=utf-8`
- It offers a lot of shortcuts hence makes the navigation very fast. It also helps to avoid redundancy by preceding any command with a number to repeat it that many number of times. (To add five times use `5p` ) Hence, beating scalability is easy with vim.